# How to use `boost::dynamic_properties` with vector valued property maps?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, dynamic-properties, boost-property-map

I would like to include a `map<string, vector<int>>` in a `boost::dynamic_properties` property:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/property_map/dynamic_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>

auto main() -> int {
  auto name2numbers = std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>{};
  auto property_map = boost::associative_property_map{name2numbers};
  auto dynamic_properties = boost::dynamic_properties{};
  dynamic_properties.property("test", property_map);
}
```

Compiling with `g++` fails with the error `no match for ‘operator<<’` for `ostringstream` and `vector<int>`:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>’} and ‘boost::associative_property_map<std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> > >::value_type’ {aka ‘std::vector<int>’})
  180 |     out << get_wrapper_xxx(property_map_, any_cast<typename boost::property_traits<PropertyMap>::key_type>(key_));
      |     ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So I decided to add a template for general vector streaming above `main`:

```cpp
template <typename OStream>
auto operator<<(OStream& output_stream, std::vector<int> const& vec)
    -> OStream& {
  for (auto item : vec) {
    output_stream << item << " ";
  }
  return output_stream;
}
```

Unfortunately, that does not help. Neither does writing a function explicitly for `ostringstream`. I always get the same error and my template does not appear in the list of candidates tried by the compiler. How can I actually tell `boost::dynamic_properties` how to write a vector of integers or at least make it try my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to “hack” solution by providing `operator<<` for a standard library type, you need to declare it in one of the associated namespaces for argument dependent lookup. Specifically you would need to declare this overload inside namespace `std` (because both std::vector and std::o stream are declared there).

However I would suggest taking more control over the specific serialization format of your property-map by using a transform_value_propertymap or function_property_map instead.

See for some examples:

- [Ouput (for GraphViz) Boost Graph vertices with their property, using as bundled property a class with private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710922/ouput-for-graphviz-boost-graph-vertices-with-their-property-using-as-bundled/50720093#50720093)
- [exporting a vector variable to graph via boost graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614317/exporting-a-vector-variable-to-graph-via-boost-graph)
- [Weight map as function in Boost Graph Dijkstra algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103659/weight-map-as-function-in-boost-graph-dijkstra-algorithm)

A search on this site will probably reveal more relevant answers by yours truly